# Adding menu item to WordPress admin bar for editors to edit one plugin's settings

Tags: admin-menu

I installed the Siteimprove plugin to my client's WordPress website and I need to provide editor access to the plugin. Editors by default do not have any access to plugins. I tried to add the following to my `functions.php`:

```
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
  add_menu_page(
        'Siteimprove Plugin',
        'Siteimprove',
        'manage_options',
        'siteimprove',
        'siteimprove_settings_form'
    );
}
```

This is the code from the Siteimprove plugin that adds it to the menu:

```
/**
 * Register menu for settings form page.
 */
public function register_menu() {
    // Add top level menu page.
    add_menu_page(
        __('Siteimprove Plugin'),
        __('Siteimprove'),
        'manage_options',
        'siteimprove',
        'Siteimprove_Admin_Settings::siteimprove_settings_form'
    );
}
```

I created a test editor account and this is not working. Am I missing something to get this working? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have read the about this function and I see you need to parameter `capability` to allows the user can see the menu as an `admin` or `editor`.

Read more the function to know detail: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

And you can try this the following code.

```
/**
 * Register menu for settings form page.
 */
public function register_menu() {
    // Add top level menu page.
    add_menu_page(
        __('Siteimprove Plugin'),
        __('Siteimprove'),
        'edit_posts',//change this line 'manage_options' to 'edit_posts'
        'siteimprove',
        'Siteimprove_Admin_Settings::siteimprove_settings_form'
    );
}
```

I hope it works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When adding a menu item, there's a capability check for 'manage_options'.  You would need to change that permission to something specific for the editor:

```
    add_menu_page(
        'Siteimprove Plugin',
        'Siteimprove',
        'edit_others_pages',
        'siteimprove',
        'siteimprove_settings_form'
    );
```

You also removed the class from the method that is run to generate the page, so you should add that back how it was in the first snippet:

```
    add_menu_page(
        'Siteimprove Plugin',
        'Siteimprove',
        'edit_others_pages',
        'siteimprove',
        'Siteimprove_Admin_Settings::siteimprove_settings_form'
    );
```

You can reference [WordPress Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for more indepth information in the Codex.

In looking into the plugin itself, I don't think just changing that is going to resolve your issues though as the plugin has other checks for the admin user in the functionality it has.

The first step I would take is to check the current user's role to first make sure they are the role you want to provide the menu and access for.  To do that I would write something like this:

```
    function wpse_318816_get_current_user_role() {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            return in_array( 'editor', $user->roles );
        }
    }
```

This uses the WordPress methods `is_user_logged_in()` and `wp_get_current_user()` to check if they are logged in, and obtain the user object.  In the user object there's a property for roles containing an array of roles available.  We can check here if the current user's role is the editor, and then add our menu like so:

```
    // Adds the siteimprove menu for the editor role's capability.
    function wpse_318816_add_editor_menu() {
        if ( wpse_318816_get_current_user_role() ) {
            add_menu_page(
                'Siteimprove Plugin',
                'Siteimprove',
                'edit_others_pages',
                'siteimprove',
                'Siteimprove_Admin_Settings::siteimprove_settings_form'
            );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_318816_add_editor_menu' );
```

This handles adding the menu in the dashboard for the editor, but then you run into the actual functionality used in the plugin there not working.  Your best bet at this point is to remap the capability for the editor on that page.

To do so, you would make use of the `map_meta_cap` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/map_meta_cap/), and check if manage_options is being used for the specific cases you want.  This prevents the editor from having too much access elsewhere in your site - ie admin privileges when they should only be editors.  Using the filter, something like this should help allow the capability that the editor role has of edit_others_pages to be used for the manage_options capability which is for admins:

```
    // Remaps edit capability to the user role.
    function wpse_318816_add_editor_cap( $caps = array(), $cap = '', $user_id = 0, $args = array() ) {
        global $pagenow;

        if ( $cap !== 'manage_options' ) {
            return $caps;
        }

        // Remove the filter to prevent resursive loops.
        remove_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse_318816_add_editor_cap', 11 );

        // Abort for admin.
        if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
            return $caps;
        }

        if ( wpse_318816_get_current_user_role() ) {

            // Check if you're on the adminpage for siteimprove.
            if ( ( $pagenow === 'admin.php' && $_GET['page'] === 'siteimprove' ) ||

                // Check if you're submitting the token request form.
                ( $pagenow === 'options.php' && $_POST['option_page'] === 'siteimprove' ) ) {

                    // Set caps to edit_others_pages for the editor role.
                    $caps = array( 'edit_others_pages' );

                    // Re-add the filter.
                    add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse_318816_add_editor_cap', 11, 4 );

                // Remove the menu page as we are remapping manage_options to edit_others_pages.
                remove_menu_page( 'siteimprove' );
            }
        }

        return $caps;
    }

    add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wpse_318816_add_editor_cap', 11, 4 );
```

One caveat I saw was of course in this particular instance the menu item is added back, so two menus are displayed.  To resolve this I just removed the custom menu we added with remove_menu_page() when the user is the plugin's pages etc.

I would suggest using this code as a plugin opposed to just adding stuff into your theme's `functions.php` file, so you don't loose the changes on updates and whatnot.  I went ahead and [created a gist so you can view the full code](https://gist.github.com/timelsass/87b24de86a9cce6633bbc55ed4213a5f). You can also [download and install the .zip](https://gist.github.com/timelsass/87b24de86a9cce6633bbc55ed4213a5f/archive/7a3671d04677eb02b02139c71019656b6d31adf6.zip) and install it as a plugin to test and modify further for your own needs.